# USB-RS232 adapter

Tags: usb, drivers, rs232

I have an USB-RS-232 adapter that when I plug it into my Windows 7 laptop comes up as a ps/2 + USB input device.

How do I go about changing this?

I don't have the original driver disk and there isn't a name on the adapter for me to go to the manufacturers website.

Is there a universal driver that I can install that will make this problem go away?

Comment: I've since discovered the adapter is a Cypress Semiconductor product.  Web info tells me I bought a paper weight.  Time to go buy myself a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two most common chips used in USB-to-RS232_serial adapters are by [FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/FTDrivers.htm) and Prolific.
Try this site for other drivers: http://www.usconverters.com/index.php?main_page=page&id=15&chapter=0.